# The Axiom of choice

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axiom-of-choice

I'm a little lost with this proof:

> If every set is equipotent to an ordinal, then we have the axiom of choice

And I want to know if someone can help or maybe give me a hint of how to proceed.

Comment: There are several different (but equivalent) formulations of the Axiom of Choice. Which one do you have to prove?

Comment: The axiom of choice is about "choosing" stuff.  Anything that is equipotent to an ordinal has the property that from any non-empty subset we can make a definitive choice, namely the first element in the well-ordering induced by the ordinal.  (By the way, I have never seen this term "equipotent" before - does it mean "has the same cardinality as"?)

Comment: @Stephen: Yes it does.

Comment: Please share your thougts and effort about this problem, it will help you to get better answers and others to do better ones.

Comment: My favorite is "equinumerous", but that seems fairly rare.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

1. To show that the axiom of choice holds it suffices to show that for every non-empty $X$, there exists a choice function on $\mathcal P(X)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$.
2. If $(A,\leq)$ is a well-ordered set then there is a choice function for $\mathcal P(A)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ definable from $\leq$.
3. If $A$ is equipotent with an ordinal then $A$ can be well-ordered.

Comment: Apparently this is a very bad answer, so I tried to revise and hint and make it better.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

- If you have a choice function for $\wp(X)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$ and a bijection $f:Y\to X$, it’s straightforward to construct a choice function for $\wp(Y)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$.
- If $\alpha$ is an ordinal, there is a very simple choice function for $\wp(\alpha)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$.